# Не запускается таймер TIM2 stm32

Tags: c, stm32

Есть программа для **stm32f031**: на ножке таймера `TIM1` есть выходной сигнал, а у второго `TIM2` ничего нет на выходе. Вроде указаны все регистры, прописаны нужные биты. Что я мог упустить?

```
#include "stm32f0xx_conf.h"
 //#include "stm32f0xx_ppp.h"

int main(void)
{
int i;
int j = 127;
uint32_t p;
RCC->AHBENR |= 0x00460000;      // Enable GPIOA, GPIOF, GPIOB clock
RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x00000800;      // Enable TIM1 clock
RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x00000001;       //Enable Tim2 clock
RCC->CFGR |= 0x04000000;        // Select system clock output
GPIOF->MODER |= 0x00004000;     // Set GPIOF7 as output
GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00020000;     // Set GPIOA8 as alternate func.
GPIOA->AFR[1] &= ~0x0000000F;     // Select AF0 (MCO) on PA8
GPIOA->AFR[1] |=  0x00000002;     // Select AF2 (TIM1_CH1) on PA8
GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~0x000000F0;     // Select AF0  on PA11
GPIOA->AFR[0] |=  0x00000020;     // Select AF2 (TIM2_CH2) on PA1

RCC->CR |= 0x00010000;      // On HSE
for (i=0; i<200000; i++) __NOP();
RCC->CFGR |= 0x00000001;        // Select HSE as system clock

TIM1->CR1 |= 0x0001;
TIM1->CCMR1 |= 0b0000000001101000;
TIM1->CCER |=  0b0000000000000001;
TIM1->BDTR |= 0x8000;
TIM1->DIER |= 0x0001;
TIM1->ARR = 255;
TIM1->CCR1 = j;
TIM1->EGR |= 0b00100000;

TIM2->CR1 |= 0x0001;
TIM2-> CCMR1 |= 0b0000000001101000;
TIM2->CCER |= 0b0000000000000001;
TIM2->ARR = 127;
TIM2->CCR1 = j;
TIM2->EGR |= 0b00100000;
TIM2->DIER |= 0x0001;
while(1)
{
//GPIOF->ODR |= 0x00000080;     // Set GPIOF7 to 1;
//for (i=0; i<100; i++) __NOP();

//GPIOF->ODR &= ~0x00000080;     // Set GPIOF7 to 0;

for (i=0; i<100000; i++) __NOP();

TIM1->CCR1 = j;

j++; if (j>=254) j=1;

//  p = GPIOB->IDR;

 // if ( (p & 0x00000040) != 0x00000000 ) GPIOF->ODR &= ~0x00000080;     
//    Set GPIOF7 to 0;
 //  else     GPIOF->ODR |= 0x00000080;     // Set GPIOF7 to 1;



      }
     }
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше писали с использованием SPL или Cube MX. Там хотя бы есть функции с человеческими названиями. А по регистрам сложно сказать, что не так. Не могу же я помнить назначение каждого бита, да и вы сами запутаетесь через некоторое время. Сильно не вникал, но по хорошему бит CEN лучше устанавливать после всей настройки.

Comment: Да я слышал что есть stm cube. Но хочется с регистрами разобраться